# Can we call the callback function using angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a pdf using jspdf and I'm using doc.html to get the innerHTML data so inside this doc.html have a mendatory callback function inside this function doc.output is declared so i need to access this doc.output and assign it to a variable so that i can it access it from another function.

```
downloadPDF(isSubmit:any) {  
    debugger      
    let doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4');    
    const content= this.pdfData.nativeElement;
    let _elementHandlers =  
    {  
      '#editor':function(element,renderer){  
        return true;  
      }  
    };
doc.html(content.innerHTML,{
            callback: function (doc) {  // i need to access this callback function from another function
              debugger
              if(!isSubmit){    
                window.open(doc.output('bloburl'))
              }else{                        
                debugger
                this.fileList = {
                  data: doc.output('datauristring'), 
                  ext: 'pdf'            
                };
              }            
            },
            margin: [194,0,146,5],
            autoPaging: true,
            x: 35,
            //y: 170,
            cellwidth:200,
            elementHandlers : _elementHandlers, 
          });
```

Updated how can i access from this function

```
 onSubmit1(event: any) {
   this.downloadPDF(true);
   this.hubxTestApprovedForPatient.base64= this.fileList;// i want to assign the callback fileslist data here
}
```

and this is my html that i call onSubmit after clicking a button

```
  <button name="Approve" mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onSubmit1($event)" form="patientReportForm"
            class="text-uppercase" [disabled]="isSubmitt" cdkFocusInitial>{{isSubmitt ? 'Saving...' : 'Approve'}}</button>
```

Comment: Use an arrow function for your callback.

Comment: i have updated the question please check i'm confused in how to get the callback data

Comment: It's asynchronous. You have to assign your data to that property from *within* your callback.

Comment: can you provide a code that i can understand

Comment: Sure, if you provide a [mre].